# Unable to interpret decoded Base64 value

Tags: base64, react-native-ble-plx

I am getting a Base64 value when I implement the monitor function from the react-native-ble-plx library.

Base64 value : **E06YXDQdOj+RrhQ9aJk3Pd4nL78V3A67/CqlO4BcED4AAAAAAAAAAA==**

When I decode this value on any online platform I get the following value: **N˜\4:?‘®=h™7=Þ'/¿Ü»ü*¥;€>**

Not sure what this exactly means. Any guidance would be of great help.
I am using Xsens DOT sensor to capture orientation data[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Fb6.png)

Comment: Most likely, you will have to interpret this data as binary data and not as a string, which then leads to this byte array: 
`13 4e 98 5c 34 1d 3a 3f 91 ae 14 3d 68 99 37 3d de 27 2f bf 15 dc 0e bb fc 2a a5 3b 80 5c 10 3e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Comment: The Base64 string most probably contains binary data, so it doesn't make any sense to convert it to a string. but without knowing the data format it's hard to figure out. You can [decode the Base64 string to hex](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex) and see if anything matches the given sample data. But your best bet would be to look on the manufacturer's home page for documentation or a SDK.

Comment: Thanks, Risto, and  @jps. I was able to convert it into a readable format. As per your suggestion, I read the manufacturer's documentation to get the data structure of the data received, converted it into an array of bytes and the data was in  IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers. Thanks again.